# How can i get a Third person perspective for a model using Aframe?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I want my A-frame camera to be behind the model and work as a TPP. I want a model to sync with the camera and rotate and move where ever the camera is moving but it should not move if the camera is pointing up and down it should not look like the model is stuck on the camera.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-physics-components@1.1.0/dist/aframe-physics-components.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands@^3.0.1/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene physics="gravity: -9.8; restitution: 0.7;" antialias="true">
    <a-assets>
      <img id="ground-grass" src="grass.jpg" />
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity universal-controls="" camera kinematic-body=""
      position="-2.9021956210846644 1.5405810531492952 -3.927244596410301"></a-entity>
    <a-plane src="#ground-grass" scale="50 50 1" repeat=" 5 5 1" rotation="-90 0 0" static-body></a-plane>
    <a-box color="#AA0000" scale="2 2 2" position="-2.5 0.5 -7.5" static-body></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

If I move the camera the box should also move.
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9IU4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be simple reparenting:

```
 <!-- The default aframe camera entity -->
 <a-camera>
   <!-- The object with the same transform as the camera + some offset -->
   <a-box position="0 0 -0.5"></a-box>
 </a-camera>
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

  <!-- "Player" -->
  <a-camera>
    <a-box position="0 -0.5 -0.65" scale="0.25 0.25 0.25" color="red"></a-box>
  </a-camera>

</a-scene>
```

---

A more complex, but flexible solution, would be creating a controller with javascript. Lets say we want to:

- Make the camera follow the box
- Make the box rotate with the camera
- Preferably not instant, but smooth.

we could do it with a component like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.2.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>

<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("follow-box", {
    schema: {
      target: {type: "selector"}
    },
    tick: (function() {
      // create once
      const tmpv = new THREE.Vector3();

      return function(t, dt) {
        if (!this.data.target) return; // ignore when there is no target
        const target = this.data.target.getObject3D("mesh"); // get the mesh
        // track the position
        const position = target.getWorldPosition(tmpv); // get the world position
        this.el.object3D.position.lerp(tmpv, 0.5) // linear interpolation towards the world position
      }
    })()
  })
  AFRAME.registerComponent("rotate-with-camera", {
    tick: (function() {
      // create once
      const tmpq = new THREE.Quaternion();
      const tmpe = new THREE.Euler();
      
      return function(t, dt) {
        if (!this.el.sceneEl.camera) return; // ignore when there is no camera
        const cam = this.el.sceneEl.camera.el; // get the camera entity
        cam.object3D.getWorldQuaternion(tmpq); // get the world rotation
          tmpe.setFromQuaternion(tmpq, 'YXZ')
          // set attribute is necesarry for wasd-controls
        this.el.setAttribute("rotation", {x: 0, y: tmpe.y * 180 / Math.PI, z: 0 })
      }
    })()
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

  <!-- camera "rig" -->
  <a-entity follow-box="target: #player" look-controls>
    <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 2"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <!-- the "player" -->
  <a-box id="player" color="red" wasd-controls="speed: 35" rotate-with-camera></a-box>
  
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Here's a [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gftruj-aframe-networked-tpp?path=public%2Findex.html%3A69%3A43) of it working in aframe networked

---

The best way would be to re-use the [orbit-controls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-orbit-controls), but afaik they won't work with wasd controls without some customization

Comment: Hi Adam, if I am moving the camera down and up then the box is looking like a sticker that is stuck in the camera. can you please help regarding that?

Comment: @SumitSharma hi how about the update?

Comment: Hi Adam, after giving rotate-with-camera rotation is not working. I want the box to change the face for example if one side of the box is in a different color I want to rotate that when pressed wasd respectively if I pressed w the face should go 180 degrees if I press d the face should go -90 degrees.

Comment: You mean leaning like a "hovercraft"? Sounds cool, I'll try to modify my answer later on :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getWorldPosition')
    at i.AFRAME.registerComponent.tick
 Hi Adam, can you please help with this I tried fixing this but was unable to succeed. I am new to A-frame that's why struggling.

Comment: Do you have it in a glitch or something where I can look it up?

Comment: Thank you, Adam. I resolved the issue somehow :) Actually, the problem was the script was executing before the assets or entity are being loaded. I gave a function so that it gets executed only after the assets are loaded.