# Add follow camera

Tags: three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

I want to add follow camera which will follow the object when I move it. As I am using a networked a-frame so my object is in the template.

```
<a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="bee" src="./bee/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

This is model.

```
<template id="bee-template">
        <a-entity
          id="fly"
          gltf-model="#bee"
          animation-mixer="clip: Rig|bee_idle"
          scale="0.02 0.02 0.02"
          look-controls
          wasd-controls
        >
        </a-entity>
</template>
```

This is a template that I'm adding to the networked scene.

```
<a-entity
        id="model"
        networked="template:#bee-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
        position="0 1 0"
        spawn-in-circle="radius:3"
        wasd-controls="acceleration: 10"
        look-controls
      >
</a-entity>
```

**So, by using this I want that camera to follow bee. Please help in this!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get a Third person perspective for a model using Aframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336022/how-can-i-get-a-third-person-perspective-for-a-model-using-aframe)

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. Thanks for this.