# Navmesh in TPP for avatar in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe, navmesh

I am using Aframe for my metaverse project and I was working with FPP where the model and camera are in same position. The navmesh is working fine there.

Now, I want to enable the TPP mode where avatar is present in front of the camera. All the nav-mesh examples which I have seen, they have given the constraintToNavmesh to Camera. But here, I want my avatar to not cross the boundaries given in the nav-mesh.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Probably you just need to apply cosntraintToNavmesh to the avatar entity.  If you provide a code sample with FPP navmesh and your avatar in the scene, it would much easier to be specific about changes required.